# set sysroot command vs set solib-search-path command

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I am confused by the commands set solib-search-path and set sysroot, not sure when to use one or another. In my case symbols are only loaded when i used both the commands. Is it always both the commands are required and what does each command does.

For here http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/, it looks like sysroot looks in subdirectories too, then why is solib-search-path required, if both search for libraries and load symbols from those libraries

Comment: @EmployedRussian, does set sysroot and set solib-absolute-prefix are identical

Comment: I think they are same

Comment: They are aliases: `help solib-absolute-prefix`: `Set an alternate system root.`

Comment: @EmployedRussian The duplicated question is not a duplicate. solib-absolute-prefix is not the same thing than solib-search-path.
This question is "set sysroot" vs "set solib-search-path". The question marked as duplicate is "set solib-search-path" vs "set solib-absolute-prefix".

Comment: Do you use absolute paths or relative? Please add examples of your paths passed to set commands.

Answer (score 2):

gdb searches first for libraries in `sysroot` (with an absolute path), and then only if it fails to find them it searches into `solib-search-path` (with a relative path).

For that reason, when using gdb server / remote debugging you probably want to use ONLY gdb's `sysroot` option. On a Linux system using `solib-search-path` will NOT work unless you change the value of `sysroot`, because the default value of sysroot is `target`, meaning that gdb is loading the so-file found on the filesystem you are debugging. This is also what is indicated in gdb's [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#:%7E:text=%27%20solib%2Dsearch%2Dpath%20%27,from%20finding%20your%20host%27s%20libraries.):

> set solib-search-path path
>
> colon-separated list of directories to search for shared libraries.
> ‘solib-search-path’ is used after ‘sysroot’ fails to locate the
> library, or if the path to the library is relative instead of
> absolute. If you want to use ‘solib-search-path’ instead of ‘sysroot’,
> be sure to set ‘sysroot’ to a nonexistent directory to prevent GDB
> from finding your host’s libraries. ‘sysroot’ is preferred; setting it
> to a nonexistent directory may interfere with automatic loading of
> shared library symbols.

As indicated in this [thread](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13989), the use-case for `solib-search-path` is rather:

> solib-search-path is there mostly to help targets like Windows that
> don't report to the debugger the full path to the shared library.
> GNU/Linux always works with full patchs, such as
> "/usr/lib/libjpeg.so.8"